# Assign Different Colors to items based on string value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

My graph looks fine but all the items have same color.  I have three types of data on the timeline and I am trying to figure out how to assign different groups different colors based on a string value.

For example, all the items that have ".txt" file extension I would to be yellow. Then all the items that have ".tnt" file extension I would like to be red. And finally, all the items that have ".doc" I would like to be green.

Right now the following code is displaying all the items on the timeline but all the items are in one color.

**Update: 11 Jan 19**

Error: Cannot read property "Event' of undefined.

```
render() {

    const array = data.abs.map(a, index) => ({id: index + 1, content: abs.Ent, start: abs.time, title: abs.Trc, end: null}))

    var new_array = new vis.DataSet();
    if (array.abs.Event.match(".exe")) {
        new_array.add({group: 1})
    } else {
        if (array.content.match(".html"))
            new_array.add({group: 2});
    }
```

Comment: does the title show up as filename.fileextension ? For example does the title show up as xxx.txt ?

Comment: Yes, the title does show up as xxx.txt.

Comment: Run each return through an if or case statement and change their color there. There is a way to check file extensions but I don't know how to do it off the top of my head. good luck

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith I struggling with the syntax for that using the restrictions of vis.js. An example would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with vis.js.

I assume it is something like 

for(let i =0; i < array.length; i++){if i === .txt i.append.red} 

Obviously this is not correct, but it would be a way to iterate through your array and change each item according to file extension.

Comment: It appears I can't do that inside the render function.

Comment: It looks like I need a DataSet according to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768598/vis-js-setoptions-to-change-color-on-network-node`

Comment: You can try using the .split(.) function on the title. This will give you an array with the file name and the extension. for example. ["xxxx","txt"] . Then you can get the second element of this array to define colors using switch statements or if statements.

Comment: Updated code. Trying to use DataSet but not sure if heading down the right road.

Comment: Updated code. Now DataSet is empty.

Comment: Is using DataSet the right way to go about this?

Comment: So if I use `array = data.abs.filter(t => String(t.Event).includes('exe')`, it finds all the exes. Now I am trying to figure out how to add a `group: 1` property to those exes.